# Toggle class to an element by click another element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click on an element to toggle a class being referenced on a completely unrelated element (not a child, parent or sibling)

For example, initially the code would look like this

```
<a id="button">Button</a>

<div class="navigation">
Foo
</div>
```

When the user clicks the element with the id `button` the HTML would change to look like this (the class "open" is referenced on element with "navigation" already referenced":

```
<a id="button">Button</a>

<div class="navigation open">
Foo
</div>
```

The user should be able to toggle the class by clicking the element with the id `button`.

I would like to use pure javascript to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach `click` event to the button with id `button` then on click select the element with class `navigation` using `getElementsByClassName()` (ti will return list of nodes) then select the first one using `[0]` then use `toggle()` :

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
     document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0].classList.toggle("open");
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0].classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
.open{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a id="button">Button</a>

<div class="navigation">
Foo
</div>
```

Comment: Why'd you include jQuery in the sample?

Comment: BTW, I think there's a classlist.toggle method

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need javascript. Checkboxes work great at storing on/off state. You just need to get a little crafty with the CSS to use it elsewhere. Here is an example:

```css
label.divcheck { color:blue; text-decoration:underline; }
input.divcheck { display:none; }

input.divcheck + div { display:none; }
input.divcheck:checked + div { display:block;}
```

```html
<label class="divcheck" for="navigation">Button Nav</label>
<label class="divcheck" for="other">Button Other</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="divcheck" id="navigation"/>
<div class="navigation">
Foo
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="divcheck" id="other"/>
<div class="navigation">
Other
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add event handlers. This can be done by simple setting the `onClick` property on the `Element` object:

```
document.getElementById('button').onClick = function onClick() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0].className += 'open';
};
```

However, it's preferable that you use `addEventListener` so multiple event listeners can be added to the same element:

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0].className += 'open';
}, false);
```

EDIT: It's also better to cache your element references in variables like so:

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
  nav.className += 'open';
}, false);
```

EDIT2: as in Zakaria's answer, you may want to use `classList.add(x)` instead of `className += x`. It's more in line with how jQuery's things work. However, be aware that `classList` is not supported in older versions of IE.

EDIT3: Here's a final version using `classList.toggle`

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
  nav.classList.toggle('open');
}, false);
```

And here's a quick replacement for `classList` using `className` instead:

```
function classList(elem) {
  var cl = {
    add: function (clas) { 
      elem.className += clas; 
    },
    remove: function (clas) { 
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(clas, ''); 
    },
    toggle: function (clas) {
      if (elem.className.indexOf(clas) > -1) {
        cl.remove(clas);
      } else {
        cl.add(clas);
      }
    }
  };
  return cl;
}

// usage
classList(nav).add('open');
classList(nav).toggle('open');
```

Comment: This is good, however it doesn't toggle the class. Rathe than continuously adding navigation, id' like to add and remove it.

Comment: replace `className += 'open'` with `classList.toggle('open')`

Answer (score 1):

### Multiple elements with class `navigation`

`navigation` is a class, so I assume there is more than one element you would like to give class `open` on click on element with id `button`. Do it that way:

```js
function toggleNavigation(element) {
  element.classList.toggle('open');
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')).forEach(toggleNavigation);
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.navigation.open {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<a id="button">Button</a>

<div class="navigation">Foo</div>
<div class="navigation">Foo</div>
<div class="navigation">Foo</div>
```

### Single element with class or id `navigation`

If it is otherwise (i.e., there is only one element with class `navigation`, in which case it should be an id, not a class) you can replace above JavaScript to:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0].classList.toggle('open');
});
```

or if you will change `navigation` to be an id:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('navigation').classList.toggle('open');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. it helps me in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('div.navigation').classList.toggle('open');
```

This will work if you only have one div element that has the class navigation. It would be better to give it an id, for example id=navigation

Comment: Using inline Javascript is a bad practice. Please do not recommend it without a disclaimer stating so.