# onmouseenter and onmouseleave events blinking like hell

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have web page as with a diamond shaped cell in it at the center and has an anime picture in it. when i hover over the image the title image of the anime must be displayed with some opacity specified when the mouse is not over the image the title image must not be displayed.I used `onmouseenter()` and `onmouseleave()` events. but when i hover over my image the title image flickers/blinks. can any one help me so that the title image doesn't flicker?

```js
function eraseName() {
  var x = document.getElementById('titleimage');
  x.style.display = 'none';
}

function displayName() {
  var x = document.getElementById('titleimage');
  x.style.display = 'block';
  x.style.opacity = '0.5';
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.container {
  background-color: grey;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img onmouseenter="displayName()" onmouseleave="eraseName()" src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
  <img
    id="titleimage"
    style="display: none;
           position: absolute;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;"
    src="https://picsum.photos/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: The image that is shown on mouse enter covers the image that handles the mouse enter event, therefore triggering a mouse leave event, which means the mouse once again triggers mouse enter on the first image, and so on and so on etc..  Can you explain exactly what you want it to do?  I get that you want the image to show, but when should it disappear?

Comment: when the mouse is not on the image. it is like showing some text on hovering over an image. Only here, i show an image when the mouse is hovered on and the image disappers when the mouse is not on the image

Comment: In that case, just change the image source - much easier than having 2 images.  Alternatively, put the mouseleave event handler on the 2nd image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do what you're looking for, but using CSS is by far the easiest, and also gives you other display options, like transitions.

Here's an example.

```js
document.getElementById("hover-image").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("You clicked the image");
});
```

```css
#main-image,
#hover-image {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

#hover-image {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#hover-image:hover {
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<img id="main-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/454/300/300"/>
<img id="hover-image" src="https://picsum.photos/id/455/300/300"/>
```

Comment: thanks it helped, but i have an onclick event on the main-image and it isn't working now. is that possible? @Archer?

Comment: Main image is hidden when the hover image is showing, so the onclick event would have to be attached to the hover image instead.  That should "just work".  Alternatively, you could have the main image in front of the hover image and have it fade out when the mouse hovers.  It seems a bit backwards but it will do what you want.  Either way will work.

Comment: I've added an example of a click handler on the image.  That should do what you need now.

Comment: i don't know why this works on stack overflow but doesn't work on my code. i changed the classes to ids and pasted the same line into my script tag. any issues?

Comment: the onclick event, there is no alert popping up when i run my page with the changes u suggested

Comment: That suggests that the script is running before the element is in the page.  Put your script tag at the bottom of the body and it should be fine.

Comment: great it works very well,but i have an ```onclick()``` event which scales the div element and the image in the div element disappears and shows some description about the image when clicked for the first time and if clicked again then the div element scales back to its normal size and the image in the div tag appears again.

Comment: can u help with this @Archer? you have been really helpful to me.

Comment: You can toggle a class on the div when it's clicked, and that can show/hide different things within the div.  For example, if the div has a class `.clicked` then you would make the elements inside the div show, but have them hidden by default.  Here's an example of toggling a class when clicked... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780825/toggle-class-to-an-element-by-click-another-element