# Change the color of the icon with click toggle only in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using this code. I would also like when it is the `display: block` the color of the label changes.

```css
label.divcheck { color:blue; text-decoration:underline; }
input.divcheck { display:none; }

input.divcheck + div { display:none; }
input.divcheck:checked + div { display:block;}
```

```html
<label class="divcheck" for="navigation">Button Nav</label>
<label class="divcheck" for="other">Button Other</label>

<input type="checkbox" class="divcheck" id="navigation"/>
<div class="navigation">
Foo
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="divcheck" id="other"/>
<div class="navigation">
Other
</div>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781115/15949286

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this without using JavaScript is to parse the label elements and position them after the input. The example for this is as follows.

```css
label.divcheck {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

input.divcheck {
  display: none;
}

input.divcheck~div {
  display: none;
}

input.divcheck:checked~div {
  display: block;
}

input.divcheck:checked~label.divcheck {
  color: red;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="divcheck" id="other" />
    <label class="divcheck" for="other">Button Other</label>
    <div class="navigation">
      Foo
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="divcheck" id="navigation" />
    <label class="divcheck" for="navigation">Button Nav</label>
    <div class="navigation">
      Other
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The problem is that my DIVs are out of sync. And I can't insert any sript or jquery code [link](https://github.com/dckiller51/lovelace-body-miscale-card/blob/e24b9aa81607bc44730bc0c06d5243572bb79fb7/body-miscale-card.js#L295)

Comment: sorry there is no other way to do this using checkbox and CSS.